# JSON decode from url in SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, url

I am trying to decode the following JSON from an URL:

```
{
"date":"2018-08-17",
"data":[
       {"id":"IDD","rate":"1.1","name":"My test ID"},
       {"id":"IDX","rate":"101.12","name":"Another test ID"}
       ]
}
```

My swift file looks like:

```
struct Container: Codable {
let date: String
let data: [MyData]
}

struct MyData: Codable {
let id: String
let rate: Double
let name: String
}

// This outputs the required json string    
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.xxx.php") {

do {
    let contents = try Data(contentsOf: url)

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jData: Container = try decoder.decode(Container.self, from: contents)

        print("The data presented is from \(jData.date)")

        for id in jData.data {
            // Here I want to get an array of the json data
            print(id.id)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

}
```

My code throws the error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

What am I doing wrong? Do you maybe also have a suggestion on how to improve my code in general?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that rate is a Double in your data class , but in your JSON rate is a string. Either change rate in your data class to:

```
let rate: String
```

Or change your JSON to have numbers in rate instead of strings:

```
{
"date":"2018-08-17",
"data":[
       {"id":"IDD","rate":1.1,"name":"My test ID"},
       {"id":"IDX","rate":101.12,"name":"Another test ID"}
       ]
}
```

edit: Sorry, I've just noticed there is already an answer basically saying the same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let rate: Double
```

Change it to:

```
let rate: String
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download the data async using URLSessionTask. Else the app will be unresponsive and lag.

Second, you should either change rate to be a String or provide a custom decoder in an custom init method to cast it to a double